# Does symfony form builder use container?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3

I put my files to [gist](https://gist.github.com/anuri73/eb740e00a1e16b0298211a967bd449a8) due to the large code.

**Description:**

[BankController](https://gist.github.com/anuri73/eb740e00a1e16b0298211a967bd449a8#file-src-apibundle-v1-controller-bankcontroller-php) of my api bundle listen the POST requests from the bank. When the controller get required variables it tries to build form HalykEntity with the HalykType.

If everything is ok and form is validated, the controller tries to call makeOperation method of HalykEntity which depend on operation type(Funding/Refunding) call appropriate methods(makeFunding/makeRefunding).

Both of them (makeFunding/makeRefunding methods) might call Banking service methods of Banking bundle.

**The problem:**

When I am trying to simulate call from bank (send post request `..AMOUNT=5201&CURRENCY=KZT&TIMESTAMP=20170906173539&TRTYPE=1..`)
I get the error:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": [
        {
            "message": "Call to a member function get() on null",
            "class": "Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError",
            "trace": [
                {
                    "namespace": "",
                    "short_class": "",
                    "class": "",
                    "type": "",
                    "function": "",
                    "file": "src\\ApiBundle\\v1\\Entity\\HalykEntity.php",
                    "line": 308,
                    "args": []
                },
                {
                    "namespace": "ApiBundle\\v1\\Entity",
                    "short_class": "HalykEntity",
                    "class": "ApiBundle\\v1\\Entity\\HalykEntity",
                    "type": "->",
                    "function": "makeFunding",
                    "file": "src\\ApiBundle\\v1\\Entity\\HalykEntity.php",
                    "line": 274,
                    "args": []
                },
                {
                    "namespace": "ApiBundle\\v1\\Entity",
                    "short_class": "HalykEntity",
                    "class": "ApiBundle\\v1\\Entity\\HalykEntity",
                    "type": "->",
                    "function": "makeOperation",
                    "file": "src\\ApiBundle\\v1\\Controller\\BankController.php",
                    "line": 34,
                    "args": []
                },
                {
                    "namespace": "ApiBundle\\v1\\Controller",
                    "short_class": "BankController",
                    "class": "ApiBundle\\v1\\Controller\\BankController",
                    "type": "->",
                    "function": "indexAction",
                    "file": null,
                    "line": null,
                    "args": [
                        [
                            "object",
                            "Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request"
                        ]
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "namespace": "",
                    "short_class": "",
                    "class": "",
                    "type": "",
                    "function": "call_user_func_array",
                    "file": "vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel.php",
                    "line": 153,
                    "args": [
                        [
                            "array",
                            [
                                [
                                    "object",
                                    "ApiBundle\\v1\\Controller\\BankController"
                                ],
                                [
                                    "string",
                                    "indexAction"
                                ]
                            ]
                        ],
                        [
                            "array",
                            [
                                [
                                    "object",
                                    "Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request"
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel",
                    "short_class": "HttpKernel",
                    "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel",
                    "type": "->",
                    "function": "handleRaw",
                    "file": "vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel.php",
                    "line": 68,
                    "args": [
                        [
                            "object",
                            "Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request"
                        ],
                        [
                            "integer",
                            1
                        ]
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel",
                    "short_class": "HttpKernel",
                    "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel",
                    "type": "->",
                    "function": "handle",
                    "file": "vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel.php",
                    "line": 171,
                    "args": [
                        [
                            "object",
                            "Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request"
                        ],
                        [
                            "integer",
                            1
                        ],
                        [
                            "boolean",
                            true
                        ]
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel",
                    "short_class": "Kernel",
                    "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel",
                    "type": "->",
                    "function": "handle",
                    "file": "web\\app_dev.php",
                    "line": 29,
                    "args": [
                        [
                            "object",
                            "Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request"
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

}

**Thoughts:**
I think the problem is that the form builder doesn't use the DI container. Am I wrong? If not, how can I call Banking service methods?

**P.S.**

Sorry I have no enough reputation to put more the 2 links. So, I have to remove some links to classes. But all of them you can find in my gist repo.

Comment: Interesting.  Never saw an error message formatted that way.  In any event, just because you made HalykEntity container aware does not mean the container is automatically injected into it. Just as a general rule, you really don't want the entity to have access to the container.  Different approaches to refactoring.  Might consider Banking::makeRefunding($entity) which would move most of the processing to the banking service.

Comment: And to answer your title question, yes the form builder uses the container to load other form types but the builder knows nothing about entities and will do a simple new if it needs to create one.  You could sort of work around the your issue by creating the entity in your controller and calling setContainer on it before passing it to the form builder.  Not recommended but it would get you past this particular problem.

Comment: @Cerad Yes, you are right. I can call Banking::makeRefunding($entity). But what if one day we have to refactor Banking service? Should I search and refactor every call of this service? In my opinion the purpose of Di Container is to leave this kind of changes.

Comment: @Cerad And why `$resolver->setDefaults( [
   'data_class'      => get_class( $this->container->get( IBankNotification::class ) ),
   'container'       => $this->container,
   'csrf_protection' => false
  ] );` does not inject container to my entity?

Comment: Think about it.  data_class contains the class name not an actual instance.  So yes the Container::get does inject the container but then you throw the actual instance away.  I suppose if you were determined you can trace the form builder code to see where data_class is used to create a new entity.  And then see if it could be tweaked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to refactor my architecture.

**Reasons:**

1. Why to pass the whole container to my entity, when I just need to pass the banking service
2. It is not good practice to pass the whole container according to best practices. (I can't find the link to doc, but I remember that the container instance is really huge and require a big amount of memory)

**Solution:**

In my Entity class, makeFunding/makeRefunding methods needs instance of Banking service

```
function makeFunding( IApiBanking $banking ): bool {
    return $banking->makeFunding();
}
```

And in my controller I've just call entity methods like:

```
/** @var HalykEntity $entity */
$entity = $form->getData();
$view   = $this->view( [
    'success' => $entity->makeOperation( $this->get( 'banking' ) )
], 200 )->setTemplate( "ApiBundle:v1:Resources:views:layouts:default.html.twig" );
```